Jupyer notebook is not opening folder
I bought a new machine, python is working fine and I installed ipython (pip install ipython) and it seems not an installation issue. When I type jupyter notebook in the command line, I get the following empty page. What is happening?
Thanks in advance
Edit
Here is the terminal output
   >>jupyter notebook
 http://localhost:8888/tree?token=549b7516f4b3ce80b3780b41d9df79636fb24a1a348d2506
    [I 2024-05-29 15:03:02.979 ServerApp]     http://127.0.0.1:8888/tree?token=549b7516f4b3ce80b3780b41d9df79636fb24a1a348d2506
    [I 2024-05-29 15:03:02.979 ServerApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 2024-05-29 15:03:02.983 ServerApp]
    To access the server, open this file in a browser:
        file:///Users/xxx/Library/Jupyter/runtime/jpserver-3035-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/tree?token=549b7516f4b3ce80b3780b41d9df79636fb24a1a348d2506
        http://127.0.0.1:8888/tree?token=549b7516f4b3ce80b3780b41d9df79636fb24a1a348d2506
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.194 JupyterNotebookApp] Missing or misshapen translation settings schema:
    HTTP 404: Not Found (Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/translation-extension/plugin.json)
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.194 JupyterNotebookApp] Settings directory does not exist at /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.225 JupyterNotebookApp] Missing or misshapen translation settings schema:
    HTTP 404: Not Found (Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/translation-extension/plugin.json)
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.225 ServerApp] 404 GET 
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.225 JupyterNotebookApp] wrote error: 'Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyter-notebook/application-extension/shell.json'
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/settings_handler.py", line 57, in get
        result, warnings = get_settings(
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/settings_utils.py", line 379, in get_settings
        schema, version = _get_schema(schemas_dir, schema_name, overrides, labextensions_path)
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyter-notebook/application-extension/shell.json)
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.227 JupyterNotebookApp] 404 GET /lab/api/settings/@jupyter-notebook/application-extension:shell?1716984185222 (607e8198a80047c4bec797dc176670c5@::1) 3.42ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.227 JupyterNotebookApp] Missing or misshapen translation settings schema:
    HTTP 404: Not Found (Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/translation-extension/plugin.json)
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.227 ServerApp] 404 GET /lab/api/settings/@jupyterlab/translation-extension:plugin?1716984185222 (::1): Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/translation-extension/plugin.json
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.227 JupyterNotebookApp] wrote error: 'Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/translation-extension/plugin.json'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1788, in _execute
        result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 3301, in wrapper
        return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/settings_handler.py", line 57, in get
        result, warnings = get_settings(
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/settings_utils.py", line 379, in get_settings
        schema, version = _get_schema(schemas_dir, schema_name, overrides, labextensions_path)
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/settings_utils.py", line 55, in _get_schema
        raise web.HTTPError(404, notfound_error % path)
    tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 404: Not Found (Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/translation-extension/plugin.json)
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.228 JupyterNotebookApp] 404 GET /lab/api/settings/@jupyterlab/translation-extension:plugin?1716984185222 (607e8198a80047c4bec797dc176670c5@::1) 3.15ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.229 JupyterNotebookApp] Missing or misshapen translation settings schema:
    HTTP 404: Not Found (Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/translation-extension/plugin.json)
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.229 ServerApp] 404 GET /lab/api/settings/@jupyterlab/apputils-extension:sanitizer?1716984185222 (::1): Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/apputils-extension/sanitizer.json
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.229 JupyterNotebookApp] wrote error: 'Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/apputils-extension/sanitizer.json'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1788, in _execute
        result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 3301, in wrapper
        return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/settings_handler.py", line 57, in get
        result, warnings = get_settings(
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/settings_utils.py", line 379, in get_settings
        schema, version = _get_schema(schemas_dir, schema_name, overrides, labextensions_path)
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/settings_utils.py", line 55, in _get_schema
        raise web.HTTPError(404, notfound_error % path)
    tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 404: Not Found (Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/apputils-extension/sanitizer.json)
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.229 JupyterNotebookApp] 404 GET /lab/api/settings/@jupyterlab/apputils-extension:sanitizer?1716984185222 (607e8198a80047c4bec797dc176670c5@::1) 1.47ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.243 JupyterNotebookApp] Missing or misshapen translation settings schema:
    HTTP 404: Not Found (Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/translation-extension/plugin.json)
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.243 ServerApp] 404 GET /lab/api/settings/@jupyterlab/application-extension:top-bar?1716984185238 (::1): Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/application-extension/top-bar.json
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.243 JupyterNotebookApp] wrote error: 'Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/application-extension/top-bar.json'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1788, in _execute
        result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 3301, in wrapper
        return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/settings_handler.py", line 57, in get
        result, warnings = get_settings(
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/settings_utils.py", line 379, in get_settings
        schema, version = _get_schema(schemas_dir, schema_name, overrides, labextensions_path)
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/settings_utils.py", line 55, in _get_schema
        raise web.HTTPError(404, notfound_error % path)
    tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 404: Not Found (Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/application-extension/top-bar.json)
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.243 JupyterNotebookApp] 404 GET /lab/api/settings/@jupyterlab/application-extension:top-bar?1716984185238 (607e8198a80047c4bec797dc176670c5@::1) 1.78ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.245 JupyterNotebookApp] Missing or misshapen translation settings schema:
    HTTP 404: Not Found (Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/translation-extension/plugin.json)
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.245 ServerApp] 404 GET /lab/api/settings/@jupyterlab/apputils-extension:notification?1716984185238 (::1): Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/apputils-extension/notification.json
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.246 JupyterNotebookApp] wrote error: 'Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/apputils-extension/notification.json'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1788, in _execute
        result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 3301, in wrapper
        return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/settings_handler.py", line 57, in get
        result, warnings = get_settings(
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/settings_utils.py", line 379, in get_settings
        schema, version = _get_schema(schemas_dir, schema_name, overrides, labextensions_path)
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/settings_utils.py", line 55, in _get_schema
        raise web.HTTPError(404, notfound_error % path)
    tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 404: Not Found (Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/apputils-extension/notification.json)
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.246 JupyterNotebookApp] 404 GET /lab/api/settings/@jupyterlab/apputils-extension:notification?1716984185238 (607e8198a80047c4bec797dc176670c5@::1) 2.28ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.246 JupyterNotebookApp] Missing or misshapen translation settings schema:
    HTTP 404: Not Found (Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/translation-extension/plugin.json)
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.246 ServerApp] 404 GET /lab/api/settings/@jupyterlab/shortcuts-extension:shortcuts?1716984185239 (::1): Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/shortcuts-extension/shortcuts.json
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.246 JupyterNotebookApp] wrote error: 'Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/shortcuts-extension/shortcuts.json'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1788, in _execute
        result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 3301, in wrapper
        return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/settings_handler.py", line 57, in get
        result, warnings = get_settings(
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/settings_utils.py", line 379, in get_settings
        schema, version = _get_schema(schemas_dir, schema_name, overrides, labextensions_path)
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/settings_utils.py", line 55, in _get_schema
        raise web.HTTPError(404, notfound_error % path)
    tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 404: Not Found (Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/shortcuts-extension/shortcuts.json)
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.247 JupyterNotebookApp] 404 GET /lab/api/settings/@jupyterlab/shortcuts-extension:shortcuts?1716984185239 (607e8198a80047c4bec797dc176670c5@::1) 2.34ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.247 JupyterNotebookApp] Missing or misshapen translation settings schema:
    HTTP 404: Not Found (Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/translation-extension/plugin.json)
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.247 ServerApp] 404 GET /lab/api/settings/@jupyterlab/extensionmanager-extension:plugin?1716984185239 (::1): Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/extensionmanager-extension/plugin.json
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.247 JupyterNotebookApp] wrote error: 'Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/extensionmanager-extension/plugin.json'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1788, in _execute
        result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 3301, in wrapper
        return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/settings_handler.py", line 57, in get
        result, warnings = get_settings(
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/settings_utils.py", line 379, in get_settings
        schema, version = _get_schema(schemas_dir, schema_name, overrides, labextensions_path)
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/settings_utils.py", line 55, in _get_schema
        raise web.HTTPError(404, notfound_error % path)
    tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 404: Not Found (Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/extensionmanager-extension/plugin.json)
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.247 JupyterNotebookApp] 404 GET /lab/api/settings/@jupyterlab/extensionmanager-extension:plugin?1716984185239 (607e8198a80047c4bec797dc176670c5@::1) 2.48ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.249 JupyterNotebookApp] Missing or misshapen translation settings schema:
    HTTP 404: Not Found (Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/translation-extension/plugin.json)
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.249 ServerApp] 404 GET /lab/api/settings/@jupyterlab/codemirror-extension:plugin?1716984185239 (::1): Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/codemirror-extension/plugin.json
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.249 JupyterNotebookApp] wrote error: 'Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/codemirror-extension/plugin.json'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1788, in _execute
        result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 3301, in wrapper
        return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/settings_handler.py", line 57, in get
        result, warnings = get_settings(
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/settings_utils.py", line 379, in get_settings
        schema, version = _get_schema(schemas_dir, schema_name, overrides, labextensions_path)
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/settings_utils.py", line 55, in _get_schema
        raise web.HTTPError(404, notfound_error % path)
    tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 404: Not Found (Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/codemirror-extension/plugin.json)
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.250 JupyterNotebookApp] 404 GET /lab/api/settings/@jupyterlab/codemirror-extension:plugin?1716984185239 (607e8198a80047c4bec797dc176670c5@::1) 2.28ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.250 JupyterNotebookApp] Missing or misshapen translation settings schema:
    HTTP 404: Not Found (Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/translation-extension/plugin.json)
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.250 ServerApp] 404 GET /lab/api/settings/@jupyterlab/docmanager-extension:plugin?1716984185239 (::1): Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/docmanager-extension/plugin.json
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.250 JupyterNotebookApp] wrote error: 'Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/docmanager-extension/plugin.json'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1788, in _execute
        result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 3301, in wrapper
        return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/settings_handler.py", line 57, in get
        result, warnings = get_settings(
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/settings_utils.py", line 379, in get_settings
        schema, version = _get_schema(schemas_dir, schema_name, overrides, labextensions_path)
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/settings_utils.py", line 55, in _get_schema
        raise web.HTTPError(404, notfound_error % path)
    tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 404: Not Found (Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/docmanager-extension/plugin.json)
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.250 JupyterNotebookApp] 404 GET /lab/api/settings/@jupyterlab/docmanager-extension:plugin?1716984185239 (607e8198a80047c4bec797dc176670c5@::1) 2.16ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.251 JupyterNotebookApp] Missing or misshapen translation settings schema:
    HTTP 404: Not Found (Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/translation-extension/plugin.json)
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.251 ServerApp] 404 GET /lab/api/settings/@jupyterlab/notebook-extension:panel?1716984185239 (::1): Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/notebook-extension/panel.json
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.251 JupyterNotebookApp] wrote error: 'Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/notebook-/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/notebook-extension/panel.json)
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.251 JupyterNotebookApp] 404 GET /lab/api/settings/@jupyterlab/notebook-extension:panel?1716984185239 (607e8198a80047c4bec797dc176670c5@::1) 2.27ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.253 JupyterNotebookApp] Missing or misshapen translation settings schema:
    HTTP 404: Not Found (Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/translation-extension/plugin.json)
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.253 ServerApp] 404 GET /lab/api/settings/@jupyterlab/console-extension:tracker?1716984185239 (::1): Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/console-extension/tracker.json
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.253 JupyterNotebookApp] wrote error: 'Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/console-extension/tracker.json'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1788, in _execute
        result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 3301, in wrapper
        return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/settings_handler.py", line 57, in get
        result, warnings = get_settings(
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/settings_utils.py", line 379, in get_settings
        schema, version = _get_schema(schemas_dir, schema_name, overrides, labextensions_path)
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/settings_utils.py", line 55, in _get_schema
        raise web.HTTPError(404, notfound_error % path)
    tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 404: Not Found (Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/console-extension/tracker.json)
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.253 JupyterNotebookApp] 404 GET /lab/api/settings/@jupyterlab/console-extension:tracker?1716984185239 (607e8198a80047c4bec797dc176670c5@::1) 2.21ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.254 JupyterNotebookApp] Missing or misshapen translation settings schema:
    HTTP 404: Not Found (Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/translation-extension/plugin.json)
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.254 ServerApp] 404 GET /lab/api/settings/@jupyterlab/notebook-extension:tracker?1716984185239 (::1): Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/notebook-extension/tracker.json
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.254 JupyterNotebookApp] wrote error: 'Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/notebook-extension/tracker.json'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1788, in _execute
        result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 3301, in wrapper
        return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/settings_handler.py", line 57, in get
        result, warnings = get_settings(
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/settings_utils.py", line 379, in get_settings
        schema, version = _get_schema(schemas_dir, schema_name, overrides, labextensions_path)
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/settings_utils.py", line 55, in _get_schema
        raise web.HTTPError(404, notfound_error % path)
    tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 404: Not Found (Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/notebook-extension/tracker.json)
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.254 JupyterNotebookApp] 404 GET /lab/api/settings/@jupyterlab/notebook-extension:tracker?1716984185239 (607e8198a80047c4bec797dc176670c5@::1) 2.07ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.254 JupyterNotebookApp] Missing or misshapen translation settings schema:
    HTTP 404: Not Found (Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/translation-extension/plugin.json)
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.254 ServerApp] 404 GET /lab/api/settings/@jupyter-notebook/notebook-extension:scroll-output?1716984185239 (::1): Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyter-notebook/notebook-extension/scroll-output.json
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.254 JupyterNotebookApp] wrote error: 'Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyter-notebook/notebook-extension/scroll-output.json'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1788, in _execute
        result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 3301, in wrapper
        return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/settings_handler.py", line 57, in get
        result, warnings = get_settings(
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/settings_utils.py", line 379, in get_settings
        schema, version = _get_schema(schemas_dir, schema_name, overrides, labextensions_path)
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/settings_utils.py", line 55, in _get_schema
        raise web.HTTPError(404, notfound_error % path)
    tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 404: Not Found (Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyter-notebook/notebook-extension/scroll-output.json)
[W 2024-05-29 15:03:05.255 JupyterNotebookApp] 404 GET /lab/api/settings/@jupyter-notebook/notebook-extension:scroll-output?1716984185239 (607e8198a80047c4bec797dc176670c5@::1) 2.31ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree


I bought a new machine, python is working fine and I installed ipython (pip install ipython) and it seems not an installation issue. When I type jupyter notebook in the command line, I get the following empty page. What is happening?

What if you run jupyterlab?

That's what I get JupyterLab application assets not found in "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab"

To open jupyter you need to open the command line on the folder where you want to create the file and run the command:
jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=`the path where the file will be'
And don't close the command line until you're done.

Did you run pip install notebook or pip install jupyterlab? Installing ipython isn't enough

@OneCricketeer  Yep, but still facing the same problem even when running jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=$HOME and installing notebook and jupyterlab successfully

what do you get in command line when you start jupyter? Maybe there are some information about problem.

@furas I have added the huge output I get

error suggests that you run MacOS. Maybe it is problem only on this system. You can always create venv and install jupyter in venv to test other copy of jupyter. And if it will work then it may need to install again with option --update or even with --force-reinstall to replace code. Or it may need to manually delete folder with jupyter before instalation.

error show HTTPError and it can't read file /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyter-notebook/notebook-extension/scroll-output.json. You could check if you have this file on disk.

It seems that your Jupyter Lab / Notebook is missing some files.
Requesting to re-install the packages with --force flag
Command to be used:

pip install jupyterlab notebook --force

If requires user permission

pip install jupyterlab notebook --force --user


Clean and Rebuild jupyter lab, as it's missing some assets
jupyter lab clean
jupyter lab build

Command to completely uninstall and then reinstall
pip uninstall notebook jupyterlab ipython -y 
pip install notebook jupyterlab

(pip3 if needed)

Are you sure these are the correct commands; I got this jupyter-lab: error: argument --reset: expected one argument?

could you please check again, the error is basically you're missing a file for jupyter lab

Tried it but it did not solve the problem:(

then please uninstall then reinstall using pip3 and when running the notebook recheck if the kernel is set to python3.*

If you want a really short straightforward solution, I would suggest you to use vs code, then creating an ipynb file or opening an ipynb file will automatically suggest you install jupyter extension, then just select python3.* as the kernel. You'll be set for running notebooks.

There are three possible options:

You cannot find the file mentioned in the error -> faulty installation, faulty build for MacOs...

Reinstallation or deinstallation + installation of something like miniconda with jupyter

You can find the file

2.1. By some reason Jupyter cannot access that folder ( some different user is used to run the Jupyter server, security system and etc.)

Can be valid for both cases

3.1 Sometimes it happens that pip installs package for one interpreter but the package is used through different interpreter. Then it is needed to check that you call right interpreter
